# Preserving symplectic structure iff matrix has unitary determinant

Tags: stochastic-processes, symplectic-geometry, stochastic-differential-equations

Let us consider a linear stochastic oscillator system: 
$$ d \begin{bmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x(t) \\y(t)\end{bmatrix}dt + \alpha \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} dW_t$$

we know that the *phase flow preserves symplectic structure*.

So, given an initial conditions and a numerical method of the form 
$$ \begin{bmatrix} x_{n+1} \\ y_{n+1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21}& a_{22} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_n\\ y_n \end{bmatrix}+ \alpha \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{bmatrix} \Delta W_n$$

we have that the **method preserves the symplectic structure iff $\det(A)=1$**, where $A$ is the matrix that appears in the numerical scheme with entries $a_{ij}$

I need to impose $d x(t) \wedge d y(t) = d x_0 \wedge dy_0$, but I really don't know how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the notation is that $d$ in the first version describes an (infinitesimal) increment relative to time, while in the last equation $d$ is the (also infinitesimal) displacement in space. Use subscripts to make a distinction, $d_t$ and $d_s$.

Then for the exact equation you get 
$$
d_t(d_sx)=d_s(d_tx)=d_s(ydt)=d_sy\,dt\\
d_t(d_sy)=d_s(d_ty)=d_s(-xdt+αd_tW)=-d_sx\,dt\\
d_t(d_sx\wedge d_sy)=d_t(d_sx)\wedge d_sy+d_sx\wedge d_t(d_sy)=0
$$
You do not get an extra Ito term because 1) $dW$ is only present in one factor and 2) its contribution is constant under space displacement. Thus $d_sx\wedge d_sy$ is constant.

The same essentially applies if you compute the evolution of $d_sx_n\wedge d_sy_n$.

Comment: But how can I get that the matrix has unitary determinant? @LutzLehmann

Comment: From $d_sx_{n+1}=a_{11}d_sx_n+a_{12}d_sy_n$ and $d_sy_{n+1}=a_{21}d_sx_n+a_{22}d_sy_n$ inserted into $d_sx_{n+1}\wedge d_sy_{n+1}$ and applying the anti-symmetry rules of the wedge or outer product.